# Unable to fetch formatted value from Excel by openxml in C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, openxml

able to fetch records from excel using openXML

```
wbPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(cellItem.CellValue.Text)).InnerText
```

and

```
cellItem.CellValue.Text
```

but values r not showing as formatted as it is in excel text.

e.g. In excel file  text : Dec09(cell format 'mmmyy') but using openxml value is 40156

In excel file  text : 26.7198404785643% but using openxml value is 0.26719840478564305

I need the value same as excel sheet.